# Add file to blob fileld in sqlite db

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I add image file, for example, with name '001.png' to sqlite3 database using its command prompt?

```
sqlite3> INSERT INTO test (id, name, blob_field) VALUES (NULL, 'Bob', ?????);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the OS you're using, you could convert the file into a hexdump and use that to construct an SQL command with a blob literal:

```sh
(printf "INSERT INTO test(id, name, blob_field) VALUES(NULL, 'Bob', 0x" ; \
 hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x"' 001.png ; printf ");" ) | sqlite3 my.db
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hex literal like  `0x123456789abcdef`

so

`INSERT INTO test (id, name, blob_field) VALUES (NULL, 'Bob', 0xB0B1);`

Comment: How can I get hex literal of 001.png file?

Comment: Read the file into a byte array in your language, and then format each byte as a hex character. Are you doing this in C# or Java?

Comment: I have found examples how to do it in C and many other langueges, but I want to write *.sql file to fill database.

Comment: yes, but you can generate the SQL file with python or other programming, for example